# How to run Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am trying to load Ubuntu 16.04.03 onto my old laptop (so old, it is running Vista).
I downloaded the program and put it onto a usb memory stick.
I assume it has everything I need, all I can see is the .iso part.
I cannot get the program to run. When I click the .iso, it wants to burn a disk, which I don't want to do. I restarted, pressing f12 key, but computer just starts normally.
I am not computer savvy at all and need a simple explanation of what I am doing wrong and what I need to do.
Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is the solution.

Download Universal USB installer: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Then use the Universial USB Installer to convert the USB into a bootable drive. This should be pretty straightforward, but if you are having trouble, view this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk5IrdifOrY

After that, close all programs and restart your computer. When it boots into the motherboard screen, there will be a key that you press to go into the bios section (F12, F10, etc.) It might take a few tries to catch it, because it comes pretty fast.

Then, after you go into your bios section, select boot options. While in boot options, you will have to select to boot from your USB drive instead of your main hard drive, which Windows is stored on.

Save the changes and exit. If you have done it correctly, Ubuntu should boot from the USB, and the install from there should be pretty straightforward.